# Testing class that insert, update and delete from the db

Tags: java, database, junit, sql-insert, sql-delete

I have class that has 3 methods: insert, update and delete from the db.
In order to test it in the insert test method I need to use the insert method and after I insert i need to delete what I inserted, but in order to delete I should use the delete method that I also want to test so it didn't make sense to me that I need to use them and also test them.

I hope you understand my problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). are you planning *UnitTests* or *acceptance tests*?

Comment: Sorry that I didn't mentioned it. I am talking about Unit Tests.

Comment: `it didn't make sense to me that I need to use them and also test them`, It make sense in Unit Test that in order to use them you should test them.

Comment: Of course that in order to use them I need to test them, but after I insert something I want to delete it because I don't want that my db had test objects. So it's not right to use the delete method in the insert test.

Comment: When you do *UnitTestig" you mock anything that is not the "unit under test" especially databases and other external resources. You have to build your tests so that they can run in any order. mocking the database acces helps here.

Comment: @Sagie Also try to test each CRUD Database operation separately, so you may not confuse your unit tests.

Comment: @Sagie could you write down your code(Update, Insert, Delete) in the answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must decide what you want to test. That was you describe, it is an integration test. By a “real” unitTest, you test only your method, and not the System method and not the database.

If you want a unitTest, you have several options. For Example, you work with interfaces and catch your statement before it comes to the database.

Edit 1 - one possibility to implement unit test with interfaces:

You need one interface that implements the method these go to the backend system:

```
public interface IDatabase{

    public returnValue insert(yourParam);

    public int update(yourParam);

}
```

Then you implement your method with the real functions in a class:

```
public class Database implements IDatabase {

    @Override
    public returnValue insert(yourParam) {
        // do something
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(yourParam){
        // do something
        return 0;
    }    
}
```

This class you call in the main class:

```
/**
 * The real class to do what you want to do.
 */
public class RealClass {

private IDatabase dbInstance = null;

    private IDatabase getDbInstance() {
        if (dbInstance == null) {
            dbInstance = new Database();
        }
        return dbInstance;
    }

    protected void setDbInstance(IDatabase dataBase) {
        dbInstance = dataBase;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getDbInstance().insert(yourParam);

    }
}
```

For the unit test you implement the interface again:

```
public class UnitTest implements IDatabase {

    @Override
    public returnValue insert(yourParam) {
        // Here can you test your statement and manipulate the return value
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(yourParam){
        if (yourParam.containsValue(value1)) {
          assertEquals("yourStatement", yourParam);
          return 1;
        }else if (yourParam.containsValue(value2)) {
          assertEquals("yourStatement2", yourParam);
          return 5;
        }else{
           assertTrue(false,"unknown Statement")
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void yourTest(){
       RealClass.setDbInstance(this);
        //Test something
    }        
}
```

This is time-consuming to implement, but with this, you are independent from the backend system and you can call the unittest every time without a database.

[image]

Comment: How can I implement this example?

Comment: If i am implementing again the IDatabase again how I test the Database class?
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: The Database class involved the system call to insert, update and delete in the Database. System method become not testing in unittest. For this you need an integration test. With the integrationtest you are testing: exist the database, write the statement into the database and so on.

Comment: Ohh, ok.
In your example, I did not understand what should I implement in the insert, update methods ib the UnitTest class. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: In the override method in the unittest, at first you can check your param. The param it contains the information you need to call the system method to write or update into the database. After that your method do something, for example after an update you check how many dataset updates done. Than you can in dependence from the incoming statement return an integer. With this you can manipulate the return value and check the different cases from your class. Maybe if you get 0 you throw an Exception.

Comment: you have implement the method insert, delete and update, because you redirect the method. The method does not insert a dataset in the database, the method go into the method in the unittest and there you manipulate it.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the order of test methods is not warrantied in JUnit. Nevertheless, as of JUnit 4.11, you can order by the test name, as follows:

```
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class Test1 {

    @Test
    public void aInsert() {
        System.out.println("first INSERT");
    }

    @Test
    public void bUpdate() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("second UPDATE");
    }

    @Test
    public void cDelete() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("third DELETE");
    }

}
```

Comment: I thought about it. It's not considered as a bad practice?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a bad practice. I don't know another way to warranty test execution order in JUnit.

Comment: I don’t think that it is bad practice, because it is an integration test. And in integration test it gives dependence and some of these process for backend systems needs an order or an initialize. In this test case  you need the database too what you should not need in unit test.